# Android EditText match_parent not working in recycler view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have an **activity** with **viewpager** inside it and inside one of the **fragment** i am using a **Recycler view** with view item as **edit text**. Here is my code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/five">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="@dimen/three" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEditorListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/et_add_item"
        android:padding="@dimen/three"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here i have given edittext width as match_parent **(    android:layout_width="match_parent")** but while running it's getting wrapped based on the width of the hint.
Can someone help me with this.

Adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteListAdapter.ListHolder> {
private List<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;

public ListAdapter(List<String> list){
    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public ListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    this.mContext = parent.getContext();
    return new ListHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.etEditorListItem.setText(mList.get(position));

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList != null ? mList.size() : 0;
}

public class ListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CheckBox checkBox;
    public EditText etEditorListItem;

    public ListHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        etEditorListItem = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etEditorListItem);
    }
}
}
```

Fragment :

```
RecyclerView rvList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvList);
rvList.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(listItems);
rvList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Fragment layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Use weight for EditText & CheckBox.

Comment: Tried that as well does not work.

Comment: Have you checked width of LinearLayout,try to set background for it to see what's width it occupied.

Comment: yes i have added background color for LinearLayout : android:background="#FFFF00" it's also behaving in the same way its width is getting wrapped as well. Figured that is because of the width of the Edit Text is getting wrapped up to its hint width.

Comment: also post your fragment xml which is containing `RecyclerView` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="#FFFF00"
android:weightSum="1"
android:padding="5dp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:padding="3dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEditorListItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"       
    android:hint="Hello"
    android:padding="3dp"/>
```

Comment: Does not work. This layout code is correct and works fine when you use it directly in your view. But same code is not working when using RecyclerView. I would like to add that i am using View pager and inside view pager recycler view is inside a fragment. So its Activity > ViewPager > Fragment > RecyclerView > View Item